# Convert tuple to list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, python-3.6

I have a dictionary like this:

```
a= {1982: [(1,2,3,4)],
    1542: [(4,5,6,7),
           (4,6,5,7)]}
```

and I want to change the all the tuples `(1,2,3,4),(4,5,6,7),(4,6,5,7)` to lists, in this case: `[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7], [4,6,5,7]`

I have tried

```
for key, value in a.items():
    for i in value:
        i = tuple(i)
```

but it does now work. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't understand your expected outcome. Do you want to convert each tuple to a list?

Comment: Sorry, I have posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to convert each tuple in a list. You can do this using a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: [list(ti) for ti in v] for k, v in a.items()}
```

will give

```
{1542: [[4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 6, 5, 7]], 1982: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]}
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: Thank you. this is it. But why can't I change it in my way.. ie. why the i in loop cannot change itself

Comment: @Zhonghao.KevinXie: Glad it solved your issue
You would have to reassign your value: something like `for key, value in a.items():
    for i, ti in enumerate(value):
        value[i]= list(ti)`

Answer (score 0):

In-place:

```
for key, value in a.items():
    for i, t in enumerate(value):
        value[i]= list(t)
```

New objects:

```
{key: [list(t) for t in value] for key, value in a.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "tupleo" library

from tupleo import tupleo.

val = tupleo.tupleToList(a[1542]).

print(val)
[[4,5,6,7], [4,6,5,7]]

tupleo gives you full depth level conversion of tuple to list.
and it have functionality to convert tuple to dict also based on index.