# Convert a tuple to a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, shapely

I have a GeoJSON output in the form of:

```
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (0.00027777777777777827, 22.000138888888873)}
```

How can I convert the value of 'coordinates' from a tuple to a list while keeping 'type' as is?

I've tried using `{k: [list(ti) for ti in v] for k, v in geom.items()}` as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731301/convert-tuple-to-list-in-a-dictionary) where `geom = geometry.mapping(geometry.Point(x, y))`but it doesn't help.

I see an error that says 'Float object is not iterable'

I'm using the shapely library

Comment: What are you doing that you specifically need a `list` rather than a `tuple`?

Comment: A tuple is the right type to use to represent a fixed pair of coordinates.

Comment: if you already know that its the `coordinates` key only, that needs changing, go old-school. iterate through the list, changing that particular key's values only for every dict. no need to create copies of the dict for no reason.

Comment: I want to insert these to BigQuery that only takes the coordinates in a list.

Comment: Can you add an example of the result you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only change the `'coordinates'` key as a list:

```
geom['coordinates'] = list(geom['coordinates'])
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [0.00027777777777777827, 22.000138888888873]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert directly as follows:

```
a['coordinates'] = list(a['coordinates'])
```

where `a` is your dict.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way, testing it via Python console:

```
>>> d = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (0.00027777777777777827, 22.000138888888873)}
>>>
>>> type(d)
<class 'dict'>
>>>
>>> d['coordinates']
(0.00027777777777777827, 22.000138888888873)
>>>
>>> type(d['coordinates'])
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
>>> list(d['coordinates'])
[0.00027777777777777827, 22.000138888888873]
```

Finally, you only overwrite the contents of the dictionary:

```
>>> d['coordinates'] = list(d['coordinates'])
```